# ParameterTable from NonlinearModelFit returns error messages

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am doing some nonlinear regression using `NonlinearModelFit` function. Here in the code I am currently working on.

```
    data = {{641.1889596602973`, 0.3515442898886446`, 0.006666666666666667`, 
   18.42787215663691`, 0.015320260698999957`}, {853.503184713376`, 
   0.6228999103456486`, 0.005`, 18.45843247530463`, 
   0.015033628445712486`}, {1065.8174097664544`, 0.9713451957052105`, 
   0.004`, 18.47681736820832`, 
   0.014815600351295102`}, {1278.1316348195328`, 1.3968801459673295`, 
   0.0033333333333333335`, 18.48909432327026`, 
   0.014721457405667875`}, {1490.4458598726114`, 1.8995047611320075`, 
   0.002857142857142857`, 18.497873570337337`, 
   0.014541527535731338`}, {645.4352441613587`, 0.3562159235817395`, 
   0.013333333333333334`, 18.30663615560641`, 
   0.01609988393043813`}, {857.7494692144375`, 0.6291133373367946`, 
   0.01`, 18.367054096714018`, 
   0.01592861839428612`}, {1070.063694267516`, 0.9791004159944073`, 
   0.008`, 18.403496664366227`, 
   0.015567677924992382`}, {1282.3779193205946`, 1.4061771595545784`, 
   0.006666666666666667`, 18.42787215663691`, 
   0.015126423750792735`}, {1494.6921443736733`, 1.9103435680173069`, 
   0.005714285714285714`, 18.44532279314888`, 
   0.015015017495969106`}, {649.6815286624204`, 0.3609183931407957`, 
   0.02`, 18.186984938903095`, 
   0.01695894614056194`}, {861.9957537154991`, 0.635357600193902`, 
   0.015`, 18.276575997715423`, 
   0.016230905228846314`}, {1074.3099787685776`, 0.986886472149566`, 
   0.012`, 18.33075557083118`, 
   0.01597520293466487`}, {1286.624203821656`, 1.4155050090077879`, 
   0.01`, 18.367054096714014`, 
   0.015129897779721974`}, {1498.9384288747349`, 1.9212132107685687`, 
   0.008571428571428572`, 18.3930697540748`, 
   0.01508543473013155`}, {653.9278131634819`, 0.3656516985658126`, 
   0.02666666666666667`, 18.068887634105025`, 
   0.017443641011041563`}, {866.2420382165606`, 0.6416326989169701`, 
   0.02`, 18.186984938903095`, 
   0.017584958821564987`}, {1078.556263269639`, 0.9947033641706852`, 
   0.016`, 18.25858724181216`, 
   0.017348685603224577`}, {1290.8704883227174`, 1.424863694326958`, 
   0.013333333333333334`, 18.30663615560641`, 
   0.016337470182677238`}, {1503.1847133757963`, 1.9321136893857895`, 
   0.011428571428571429`, 18.34111192991075`, 
   0.015260497452979417`}, {641.1889596602973`, 0.3515442898886446`, 
   0.006666666666666667`, 18.42787215663691`, 
   0.015930128581293182`}, {853.503184713376`, 0.6228999103456486`, 
   0.005`, 18.45843247530463`, 
   0.01579643073515604`}, {1065.8174097664544`, 0.9713451957052105`, 
   0.004`, 18.47681736820832`, 
   0.015694708199732864`}, {1278.1316348195328`, 1.3968801459673295`, 
   0.0033333333333333335`, 18.48909432327026`, 
   0.01560010574685976`}, {1490.4458598726114`, 1.8995047611320075`, 
   0.002857142857142857`, 18.497873570337337`, 0.01524091158049381`}};
    
    model = a*P^b*Q^c*R^d*S^e;
    fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d, e}, {P, Q, R, S}];
    fit["BestFitParameters"]
    fit["ParameterTable"]
```

The command `fit["BestFitParameters"]` works just fine but `fit["ParameterTable"]` returns error messages `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered...` I don't know what's going on here. Is there a way to fix this? I am using Mathematica version 12.1.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Take a look at `Correlation[data[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]] // MatrixForm` or look at all pairwise plots of the predictors.  You'll see that $P$ and $Q$ are almost perfectly correlated and so are $R$ and $S$.  In short, your model is overparameterized given the available data.  It is not a problem with *Mathematica*.  Any other software would have the same issues.